# libicui18n.so.69 missing PostgreSQL ArchLinux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, postgresql

**Problem:**

I tried to install PostgreSQL following the tutorial from the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL).

As the postgres user, when running the following command:

```
[postgres]$ initdb -D /var/lib/postgres/data
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/postgres: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.69: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
no data was returned by command ""/usr/bin/postgres" -V"
```

**What I've tried:**

I've tried reinstalling Postgres and syncing the repositories with no effect.

**Question:**

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libicui18n.so.69 is part of the [icu](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/icu/) package, which should have been installed as a dependency when installing postgresql. If you do not have installed in the correct version (69.1-1, check `pacman -Qi icu` for the currently installed version), you have likely done a partial upgrade (possibly to install postgresql?) and need to upgrade your whole system with `pacman -Syu`. Partial upgrade on Archlinux are [not supported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported).